# Contingency matrix to 1D format in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, entropy, contingency

2x2 contingency matrix:

```
     Cj
    2  1
Ci
    1  0
```

Translates to:

```
[[ 0 0 0 1 ]
 [ 0 0 1 0 ]]
```

The contingency matrix represents the outcome of two clustering algorithms, each with two clusters. The first row indicates that `Ci` has three data points in, say, cluster 1 and one data point in, say, cluster 2. `Cj` has three data points in, say, cluster A and 1 data point in, say, cluster B. Therefore, both algorithms "agree" on two out of N = 4 data points.

Since there does not exist an adjusted mutual information function that takes in the contingency matrix as input, I would like to transform the contingency matrix to 1d inputs for the sklearn implementation of AMI.

Is there an efficient way to re-write a NxN contingency matrix in 1D vector form in Python code?

It would look something like:

```
V1
V2
For i row index 
  For j column index
     Append as many as contingency_ij elements with value i to V1 and with value j to V2
```

The output should always be two vectors. Another example:

```
2 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

Would lead to two 1D vectors:

```
0 0 1 2
0 0 1 2
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  You've posted LaTeX code there -- is that relevant to the question at all?  You can't really express a 2D matrix in 1D, but of course Python supports 2D matrices.  What do you expect to DO with this data?

Comment: @Tim I imagine OP tried to format their matrix. It would be better to use a markdown table, or simple text in between triple backticks.

Comment: I think some details on the logic would be helpful

Comment: If you can explain how `[[2,1],[1,0]]` becomes `[[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0]]`, then I'm sure we can come up with code to do it.  Neither of those is 1D, of course.

Comment: @TimRoberts Indeed, LaTeX was for formatting purposes. The contingency matrix represents two clustering outcomes, each having two clusters. But I'll edit the question.

Comment: Please provide a reference implementation which includes inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this solves the problem as you have stated it.  The final matrix `v` can be converted to numpy.  `v` would need as many empty elements as there are dimensions in `c`.

```
def produce_vectors( c ):
    v = [[],[]]

    for i,row in enumerate(c):
        for j,val in enumerate(row):
            v[0].extend( [i]*val )
            v[1].extend( [j]*val )
    return v

c = [[2,1],[1,0]]
print(produce_vectors(c))
c = [[2,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
print(produce_vectors(c))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]]
[[0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: The final output should ALWAYS be two vectors, even if c is larger than 2x2 or non-squared, as input for sklearn.metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score(labels_true, labels_pred, *, average_method='arithmetic')

Comment: Is there a way to make the size of v flexible depending on c?

Comment: It already does that.  Have you looked at the code?  The two output vectors grow as required.  Each will end up as long as the sum of all the values in `c`.  The NUMBER of vectors in `v` depends only on the number of DIMENSIONS in `c`.  Since it is 2D, there will be 2 vectors.

Answer (score 0):

A numpy implementation could take advantage of [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
# input contingency matrix
a = np.array([[2,1],[1,0]])
# fixed "cluster id" matrix
b = np.array([[0,1],[0,1]])
out = np.vstack([np.repeat(b.ravel('F'), a.ravel()),
                 np.repeat(b.ravel(), a.ravel())
                 ])
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Other example with `[[5,4],[0,3]]` as input:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

You can also use cluster ids other that 0/1, if wanted (example with `a = np.array([[5,4],[0,3]]) ; b = np.array([[0,1],[2,3]])`):

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: is there a way to make this work for any nxn contingency matrix, now I am getting the error: "operands could not be broadcast together with shape"

Comment: can you provide a larger example?

Comment: Another example is in the question